# Tuning Sql Query With Multiple Inner Joins On Same Table

Tags: postgresql

Because of the structure of the database tables, I have to perform the following query by performing a series of inner joins on the same table.  Is there any way to optimize such a query?

The query plan is here: http://explain.depesz.com/s/vAvx

```
SELECT 
cch.id || '|' || ff.id || '|' || fc.id || '|' || tf.id || '|' || tc.id AS id,
cch.id as compare_cache_header_id, cch.client_id, --[ADDED]
base_env_adapter_id, changed_fund_config_id, type, 
true AS new_money, 'BOTH'::text AS online_transfer, 'BOTH'::text AS automatic_transfer, true AS short_term_fee, true AS rebalancing, '*'::text AS target_units, 'ALL_INTERFACES'::text AS trade_allowed,
from_fund_code, 
ff.en_short_display_name as from_fund_en_short_display_name, ff.en_med_display_name as from_fund_en_med_display_name, ff.en_long_display_name as from_fund_en_long_display_name, 
ff.fr_short_display_name as from_fund_fr_short_display_name, ff.fr_med_display_name as from_fund_fr_med_display_name, ff.fr_long_display_name as from_fund_fr_long_display_name, 
to_fund_code, tf.en_short_display_name as to_fund_en_short_display_name, tf.en_med_display_name as to_fund_en_med_display_name, tf.en_long_display_name as to_fund_en_long_display_name,
tf.fr_short_display_name as to_fund_fr_short_display_name, tf.fr_med_display_name as to_fund_fr_med_display_name, tf.fr_long_display_name as to_fund_fr_long_display_name, 
cct.from_class_code, fc.english_name as from_class_english_name, fc.french_name as from_class_french_name, fc.en_display_name as from_class_en_display_name, fc.fr_display_name as from_class_fr_display_name,
cct.to_class_code, tc.english_name as to_class_english_name, tc.french_name as to_class_french_name, tc.en_display_name as to_class_en_display_name, tc.fr_display_name as to_class_fr_display_name
FROM compare_cache_header cch
INNER JOIN compare_cache_transfer cct
ON cch.id = cct.compare_cache_header_id
INNER JOIN fund ff
ON cch.changed_fund_config_id = ff.fund_config_id and cct.from_fund_code = ff.fund_code
INNER JOIN fund tf 
ON cch.changed_fund_config_id = tf.fund_config_id and cct.to_fund_code = tf.fund_code
INNER JOIN class fc
ON cch.changed_fund_config_id = fc.fund_config_id and cct.from_class_code = fc.class_code
INNER JOIN class tc
ON cch.changed_fund_config_id = tc.fund_config_id and cct.to_class_code = tc.class_code
WHERE cct.type = 'ADD';
```

Comment: As most of the time of the query is spend in the hash joins I think the speed of the query comes mostly down to having enough work_mem and cpu speed. The amount of work_mem can be set from your postgresql.conf but be careful setting it to high can cause serious performance problems when handling many concurrent queries as your server might start swapping. If you already have enough work_mem setting it higher won't have any effect as enough is enough. BTW 628ms seems ok to me for a query with that many joins and a 100,000 row result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are indexes defined on all of the fields in all of the ON clauses and all of the WHERE clauses. It should be fairly quick otherwise.

Comment: I have indices on the following columns: compare_cache_header_id, compare_cache_transfer_id, changed_fund_config_id, from_fund_code, to_fund_code, from_class_code, to_class_code already.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You seem to have indexes on most columns where they could be usefull. However indexes are mostly helpful for replacing inefficient sequential scans with index scans. While there are some sequential scans in the plan they only take up 0.1% of the query time so nothing to gain there.